# Как поставить значёк для приложения в Tkinter при компиляции в .exe

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

Как поставить значёк для приложения в Tkinter при компиляции в .exe.
Ведь стандартная функция `root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')` меняет значёк только если он сохранён на ПК. А мне нужно сделать переносное приложение.
Пожалуйста обьясните мне максимально просто ведь я очень плохо разбираюсь в Python.

Comment: Если мне нужно будет пользоваться не библиотекой PyInstaller, то подскажите как скрыть консоль, компилировать в один файл и установить логотип приложению, Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `не библиотекой PyInstaller`, а какой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь указание иконки для пайинсталлера, например:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=icon.ico --add-data "icon.ico" app.py
```

А --windowed скроет консоль. --add-data упакует иконку вместе с кодом.

В самом коде ещё надо указать относительный путь к иконке на случай когда рабочая директория другая.

```
import pathlib,os.path
appdir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
root.iconbitmap(os.path.join(appdir,'icon.ico'))
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось

Comment: @Danil галочку поставь